# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xb3d5e488 in tid 8058

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have a simple ndk code in my app and im keep getting this error in the logcat and app keep crashing. Here is the method where app is crashing:

```
char VAL1[] = "abcdef";
char VAL2[] = "123456";
char VAL3[] = "helloworld";
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_livetv_android_apps_uktvnow_utils_Constants_getValue(JNIEnv *env , jobject thiz, jstring date, jstring completeUrl, jstring params){
const char *nativeDate = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(date, 0);
const char *nativeUrl = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(completeUrl,0);
const char *nativeParams = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(params,0);

char token[] = "";
jstring returnVal;
strcat(token,nativeDate);
strcat(token,VAL1);
strcat(token,nativeUrl);
strcat(token,VAL2);
strcat(token,nativeParams);
strcat(token,VAL3);

(env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(date, nativeDate);
(env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(completeUrl, nativeUrl);
(env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(params, nativeParams);
returnVal =  (env)->NewStringUTF(token);
return returnVal;
}
```

The point of this method is to receive some string from java code and concatenate that string with some other values and return a `jstring`. Bellow is my LOGCAT:

```
06-03 17:20:05.452 8861-8861/com.livetv.android.apps.uktvnow A/libc:Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x745f7773 in tid 8861 (id.apps.uktvnow)
06-03 17:20:05.504 193-193/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-03 17:20:05.504 193-193/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48T/2237560:user/release-keys'
06-03 17:20:05.504 193-193/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
06-03 17:20:05.504 193-193/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
06-03 17:20:05.504 193-193/? I/DEBUG: pid: 8861, tid: 8861, name: id.apps.uktvnow  >>> com.livetv.android.apps.uktvnow <<<
06-03 17:20:05.504 193-193/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x745f7773
06-03 17:20:05.518 1320-1457/? I/Icing: Indexing done 56E76EE85DF9759742239162095EE2BD5D47F19A
06-03 17:20:05.525 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     r0 b75c5408  r1 6e656b70  r2 6e656b6f  r3 745f7777
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     r4 745f776f  r5 be872fa0  r6 b6e55dd4  r7 781cdd54
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     r8 be872ee4  r9 be872ef4  sl b520b2f0  fp b75c1370
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     ip b6e5196c  sp be872dc8  lr b4ff49f7  pc b517a92c  cpsr 300b0030
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0023992c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+151)
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000b39f3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckInstance(art::ScopedCheck::InstanceKind, _jobject*)+74)
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000b45ef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckEbPKcz.constprop.129+762)
06-03 17:20:05.526 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000be575  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::ReleaseStringUTFChars(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, char const*)+68)
06-03 17:20:05.527 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000e69  /data/app/com.livetv.android.apps.uktvnow-2/lib/arm/libConstants.so (Java_com_livetv_android_apps_uktvnow_utils_Constants_getValue+156)
06-03 17:20:05.527 193-193/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0114fe2a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-non moving space (deleted)
```

So can please someone help me with this? 
Thanks.

Comment: You've only allocated a single byte of storage in token.  char token[] = ""

Comment: so it means i cant add more byte (string values) in token[]?

Comment: Since your native code appears to be C++, why aren't you using `std::string` (which has a `+=` operator for appending)?

Comment: @Michael because there i get error the no 'string' found in std scope.

Comment: Well, you would need to include the correct header and specify an STL implementation in your Application.mk or gradle script.

Comment: As the comment below says, use correct STL library, in my case I usually use gnustl_shared  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html?hl=es

Comment: Turns out @Michael answer was the correct, there was some error in string concatenation.

Comment: @awaistoor There was no 'error in string concatenation'. There was an error in the initial allocation, which was inadequate to the purpose to which it was subsequently put. The string concatenation code merely exposed that problem. It wasn't erroneous in itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] token = "";
```

This means that `token[]` is an array of length 1, and you've appended a number of string to it of total length much more than 1, so you've corrupted the memory beyond it.

Solution: declare it big enough for the data you're gout to put into it.