# ReleaseStringUTFChars in JNI makes crash (SIGSEGV)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am using this code in JNI within the android studio. some use-case makes crash and other works at runtime. perhaps it was related to the memory leak. 
I am getting this error:
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xffffffffdeadbaad))

jstring jstr1 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");
    char *m1 = (char *)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,jstr1, 0);

```
jstring jstr2 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "-");
char *m2 = (char *)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,jstr2, 0);

jstring jstr3 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");
char *aaa = (char *)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,jstr3, 0);

// ...

strcat(aaa,m1);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr1, m1);//no problem

strcat(bbb,m2);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr2, m2);//no problem

strcat(str,aaa);
//(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr3, aaa);//crash

strcat(str,bbb);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr4, bbb);//no problem

strcat(str,m3);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr5, m3);//no problem

strcat(str,ccc);
jstring res = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);
//(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr6, str);//crash
```

Comment: i read this but i don't understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614381/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-2-fault-addr-0xb3d5e488-in-tid-8058

Answer (score 5):

```
char *aaa = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(...);
// ...
strcat(aaa, ...);
```

You can't do this. `aaa` was derived from `GetStringUTFChars()`. You can't go around appending to it. It's not yours. Append to your own data, in your own memory space.

Comment: thanks... i solved the problem with local char array vars... .

Answer (score 2):

Create your own output before filling it.

```
char *output = (char *) calloc( strlen(aaaa) + strlen(m1), sizeof(char) );     
strcpy( output, aaaa );
strncat( output, m1, strlen(m1) );
```